# How can I make a button trigger an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a textbox and a button.

After entering text I want to click the button such that a AJAX get's made.
The AJAX call will grab the text and update it on a existing JSON file.The JSON file will get saved. This is my objective i.e. having a updated JSON file.

[image]

So my question is am I on the right track here. I am new to asp.net and want to confirm that these steps are possible. Is there a easier way to trigger an AJAX call with a click?

Comment: Asking for an easier way doesn't make sense if you haven't given us anything to compare to. Yes, it is possible to do, though since i'm not familiar with asp i won't of much help for making a demo.

Comment: code... where are youuuuuu

Comment: You are writing code. *Anything* is possible as long as you understand  the inherent structure of the systems you work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure weather it makes a difference whether you're using asp.net or not, but here is an example of triggering ajax on click of a button.

```
var doAjax = function(inputValue) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/mysever/page.asp', // .asp?
       type: 'POST'
       data: { value: inputValue },
       success: function( response ) {
          // do something with response
       }
    });
};

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var fieldValue = $('#myInputField').val();
    doAjax(fieldValue);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need an onClick event to call a function, which will get (fetch) your field value and push it to an AJAX request, like so:

```
function postValue() {

  // fetch the field value
  var val = $('#my_input').val();

  // verify the field was not empty
  if (val.length>0) {
    // setup post object
    var ajax_post = {myText : val};

    // EXECUTE AJAX 
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
       url  : 'save-values.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : ajax_post
    })
    .done(function() {
        //alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        //alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        //alert( "complete" );
    });

  } else {
    //alert( "error: please enter a value!" );
  }

}
```

Then just attach this to your button:

```
<button onClick="postValue();" value="Click Me!">
```

Note, this was done with jQuery but it can be done with vanilla javascript just the same.

Good luck!